# Selecting and install files of only one feature from two different feature conditionally in installshield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I have three features F1, F2 and F3. User can select only one of feature F1 or F2. 
F3 is a default feature.Files are distributed between these two features F1 and F2. 
If user selects F1, files of F1 should be installed. If user selects F2, files of F2 should be installed. Not sure if installshield has an option on this. How can I proceed on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done by adding a radio control in custom setup dialog box with behavior logic of next button set to

```
    Event : ADDLOCAL Argument : <FeatureName> Condition :<Radio Group Property = Radio Button Value>
   Event : REMOVE Argument : <FeatureName>  Condition : <Radio Group Property <> Radio Button Value>
```