# InstallShield - Feature groupto select only one

Tags: installshield

I have set of features, and sub-features on a feature. That sub-feature set need to act like a group box, where only feature should able to select.

```
-Feature A
-Feature B
---Feature I
---Feature II
---Feature III
-Feature C
```

From the list above, only on from I, II and III can be selected. On documentation I couldn't find a feature selection events, so that I could deselect other items based on that. Can't we do this with InstallShield?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and install files of only one feature from two different feature conditionally in installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536878/selecting-and-install-files-of-only-one-feature-from-two-different-feature-condi)

Comment: I want to have a look, as it can done via the custom dialogs only. Will asses with the other configurations.